# Указанное расположение исполняемого файла задачи является недопустимым

Tags: c++, драйвер

При попытке собрать проект драйвера в VS 2017 (WDK 10 и SDK 10) возникает ошибка MSB6004:

> Указанное расположение исполняемого файла задачи "\stampinf.exe" является недопустимым

Чем может быть вызвана эта ошибка?